# Filter a nested arrays of structs and return the child object in swift

Tags: swift, filter, closures

I have read multiple discussions about filtering nested arrays in swift, however they all return the parent object.

Let's have these simple data:

```
struct MenuSection: Identifiable {
    let id: id
    var name: String
    var menuRows: [MenuRow]
}

struct MenuRow: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: id
    var name: String
}

private let menuSections: [MenuSection] = [
    MenuSection(id: 0, name: "Menu Group 1", menuRows: [
        MenuRow(id: 0, name: "Menu 1")
    ]),
    MenuSection(id: 1, name: "Menu Group 2", menuRows: [
        MenuRow(id: 1, name: "Menu 2"),
        MenuRow(id: 2, name: "Menu 3")
    ])
]
```

My goal is to get the MenuRow with its id.

So, I create this function and it works:

```
func getMenuRowWithId(menuRowId: id) -> MenuRow? {
    for menuSection in menuSections {
        for menuRow in menuSection.menuRows {
            if menuRow.id == menuRowId {
                return menuRow
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

However, I want to do something more swifty (and maybe more efficient).

I tried something like:

```
var filtered = menuSections.filter { $0.menuRows.filter { $0.id == 1 }.count != 0  }
```

but it's returning the MenuSection containing the right MenuRow.
=> I only want the menuRow.

I have tried many things, such playing with compactMap/flatMap to flatten the array before filtering. No way.

How can I browse the menuSections and obtain ONLY the right menuRow ?
Thanks

Comment: In your example you have more than one MenuRow object with the same id yet you only want one object returned. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: If each id is unique or you only care about the first match then you can do `menuSections.flatMap(\.menuRows).first(where: { $0.id == 1 })`

Comment: Sorry Joakim. I maded the change for all ids to be unique. (in fact, I used UUID but I simplify the post with Int as IDs.

Comment: Fine then my code above solves your problem, right?

Comment: Yes, it's working ! Thanks a lot Joakim. I wasn't using flatMap like you. Can you just tell me what means the "\" before menuRows and why it's required ?

Comment: @alex.bour That's a [keypath](https://sarunw.com/posts/what-is-keypath-in-swift/) which since Swift 5.2 ([SE-0249](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md)) can implicitly converted to a closure. In this context, it's the same as `.flatMap({ $0.menuRows })`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You should post your solution as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` first to get all MenuRow objects in one array and then find the correct object in that array using `first(where:)`

```
let menuRow = menuSections.flatMap(\.menuRows).first(where: { $0.id == 1 })
```